# How to translate callbacks to kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to make this request with Kotlin:

```
One one = One.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
one.sendInteraction("/interactionName", new GetCallback<ResponseObject>() {

    public void done(ResponseObject response, ThunderheadException e) {
        if (e == null) {
             // Success!
            one.processResponse(response);
        } else {
            // Failure!
        }
    }
});
```

When I try to convert on Android Studio translator the code not fit well. I am a newbie with Kotlin, I tried some ways but always fail.
My problem it's with callback method

```
new GetCallback<ResponseObject>() { public void done(ResponseObject response, ThunderHeadException e){...}}`
```

Could you help me to find the way to do it in Kotlin?

Comment: Think that the Java code already lacks the `@Override` annotation; invalid Java input = invalid Kotlin output. And also, you are missing the call to `one.init()`, as the [documentation](https://github.com/thunderheadone/one-sdk-android) shows.

Comment: Hi Martin, noops. I call one.init() on application class and it works. The problem that I have it's related to the callback, of the sendinteraction method. I will try the solution that André Simón has posted.

Comment: @Override is optional in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you implement the interface using the object keyword. It might look something like this:

```
one.sendInteraction("/interactionName", object : GetCallback<ResponseObject> {
    // ...
})
```

Then follow the autocomplete instructions from IntelliJ to override the functions.

Comment: Hi André it works, the documentation has several mistakes. Thank you for you help!

Comment: Great to hear. Please mark the answer as accepted answer and leave an upvote so that future readers can see this! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When the callback has only one method, you can treat it like a lambda:

```
one.sendInteraction("/interactionName") { response, e ->
    if (e == null) {
         // Success!
        one.processResponse(response);
    } else {
        // Failure!
    }
}
```

Comment: When the callback has only one method _and is defined in Java_ (until Kotlin 1.4)

Comment: Hi, this solution works fine! @Tenfour04 Thank you very much. This solution it's the most successfull in my opinion.

Comment: Note Alexey Romanov's comment. This doesn't work for interfaces defined in Kotlin yet. And if the interface has more than one method, look at the other answer for the syntax.